# Maven: Where to put generated resources for tomcat-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, tomcat, maven, maven-plugin, maven-tomcat-plugin

I have CSS and JavaScript files in `src/main/webapp` directory of my project.
I want to join add joined and minified version of these resources to my WAR file and to the place where `tomcat-maven-plugin` picks it up.

I used yuicompressor-maven-plugin to create the files and put it to `${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}`. It works great for maven package and those resources make their way to WAR file, but somehow `tomcat-maven-plugin` does not see those at all. Should I use a different directory for it?

My pom:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/MyApp</path>
                <warDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</warDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <optimize>true</optimize>
                <debug>true</debug>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
                        <includes>
                            <include>context.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <aggregations>
                            <aggregation>
                                <output>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/js/commons-pack.js</output>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/../webapp/js1.js</include>
                                    <include>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/../webapp/js2.js</include>
                     ...
```

What should I do to make  `mvn tomcat:run` to also pick up my generated files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `warSourceDirectory`:

```
<warSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</warSourceDirectory>
```

Instead of this configuration property (`warDirectory`) for the `tomcat-maven-plugin`:

```
<warDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</warDirectory>
```

According to the [tomcat-maven-plugin documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html), `warSourceDirectory` is where the web resources get picked up, and its default value is `${basedir}/src/main/webapp`.  This means that if you don’t set that property, you need to generate your unified/minified JavaScript file under `${basedir}/src/main/webapp`.

If you set `warSourceDirectory` to the output folder, this means you need to generate this file before starting Tomcat.

Comment: After setting warSourceDirectory website stopped working :) Did I miss something? May be I should move everything to that directory?

Comment: If you set `warSourceDirectory` to a `build` folder, you must do a `mvn package` before hand to actually process the resources.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can also use the `run-war` goal instead of `run`, e.g. `mvn tomcat6:run-war`. This wil use the exploded war in your build directory (and thus filtered resources). See [this site](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat6-maven-plugin/run-war-mojo.html). There is also `run-war-only` which skips the packaging phase.

Answer (score 1):

Note the plugin is now maintained at Apache (so upgrade a bit :-) ) see http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/.

Even it works using install I'm not sure it's the optimum solution (regarding io and build time).

The tomcat run must be able to use resources from more than one directory (I'm not sure  it's possible with the current tomcat embeded api).

Can you add a feature request here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MTOMCAT

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to copy all static resources (webapp) to, say, target/ directory and point tomcat there?

Comment: possible using http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html